# AWS S3 Path having a fixed string in the middle

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was wondering if there is any difference between the below two paths. The first path has a fixed string in between. Will it have any kind of performance impact? S3 [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/optimizing-performance.html) mentions that they allow 3,500 PUT/COPY/POST/DELETE or 5,500 GET/HEAD requests per second per prefix in a bucket. And since both path below have a random prefix therefore we should be fine.

```
random_uuid/<some_fixed_string>/random_uuid
```

vs

```
random_uuid/random_uuid
```

Any pointers or help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 has a flat hierarchy and there are actually no folders. The names:

```
random_uuid/<some_fixed_string>/random_uuid 

random_uuid/random_uuid
```

are both keys and the folder-subfolder hierarchy is imposed by the client. In S3 the items are simply stored with a key name and the '/' doesn't mean anything. Therefore they should be fully equivalent.